# Background camera from same scene in BGE

Tags: camera

Is there a way I can set up one camera to play in the background of another camera in the same scene in BGE? The two cameras need to be parented to the same object, but one has to be in the background. I'm using two cameras because one has to be in orthogonal and the background one in perspective.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem a different way, not with cameras in the same scene necessarily, but with a master camera in one scene and the active slave cameras in all the other scenes. Here was my other question where this was explained by the friendly Monster: [How to get a camera to copy location of character from a different scene in BGE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106159/how-to-get-a-camera-to-copy-location-of-character-from-a-different-scene-in-bge)
P.S. I wasn't asking the same question twice, I thought the cameras needed to be in the same scene at first, but then I thought maybe they could still be in different scenes, so I asked the second question. ;)